# convert numbers in string to double array few code lines c#

Tags: c#, arrays, split, data-manipulation

I have string contains three numbers which `seperated by comma or by space`.

For example: `"3,3,3" or "3 3 3"`.

The string can contains also spaces between the numbers or at the start\end of the string.

I want to `insert them into array`.

I did:

```
this.ang[0] = Convert.ToDouble(ang.Trim().Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
this.ang[1] = Convert.ToDouble(ang.Trim().Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]);
this.ang[2] = Convert.ToDouble(ang.Trim().Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2]);
```

How can I insert the data into the array with less code lines?

Thanks!

Comment: Move your conversion logic to a method and use a `for` or `foreach` loop to populate the array.

Comment: @Sylverac Any way doing it without loop?

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp this solve my issue

Comment: @Programmer Yeah just do each assignment manually. i.e. `ang[0] = MyConversionMethod(inputString);`, `ang[1] = MyConversionMethod(inputString);`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method already returns an array, so you could perform your split and use LINQ's [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) method to to parse each value as a double and store these values in an array :

```
// This will store the double value for each of your elements into an array
this.ang = ang.Trim().Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x))
                     .ToArray();
```

If you can't explicitly set your `this.ang` array, then you could store the previous result in a variable and use it to set the individual values as necessary.

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AeaHGs).

Answer (score 1):

You try using *Linq*:

```
 String ang = "3,3,3"; 

 double[] result = ang
   .Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item))
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The already suggested answers suppose that you can re-assign the entire array `ang`. If you can't, you have to pass through a for iteration:

```
var splitString = ang
    .Trim()
    .Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    this.ang[i] = Convert.ToDouble(splitString[i]);
}
```

Comment: *Magic value* `3` in `i < 3` looks ugly; `i < this.ang.Length`?

Comment: Sure. Maybe in the future `ang` will have 5 or 10,000 doubles, so maybe you can generalize it even more making a constant like `public const int ANG_LENGHT = 3`;

Answer (score 0):

```
var ang = "3,3,3"; // or "3 3 3";
var res = ang.Trim().Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x))
                    .ToList();
```